# How to edit content after website goes live in digital ocean?

Tags: django, hosting

I hosted a Django website in `digitalocean.com`,  Now it is live I don't know how to edit it..

I tried this approach, but didn't work:

1. edited the content of website
2. pushed it to GitHub
3. Pull it from `digitalocean` root user

I saw all changes took effect in GitHub and my files in `digitalocean` but it doesn't work. I resarted `nginx`, still nothing works as expected. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: if you are using gunicorn/apache, then restart those as well

Comment: I am using gunicorn

Comment: I restarted gunicorn `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn` and nginx `sudo systemctl restart nginx`. No result

Comment: can you check the server and see if the changes you made exists in the server? Also what changes did you made?

Comment: yes, I already check that those changes took place in either in GitHub and after pulling in server side as well

Comment: am I using the right command